# Unable to add options in a listbox using JQuery in IE however works fine in firefox

Tags: jquery

I have a small JQuery code to Populate/Filter a list box based on a drop down value. However its working fine in Firefox but throws invalid argument error when adding option to list box at following line of code in IE9.

```
catvalues.add(el);
```

here is the complete code:

```
var names = $('#names');
$('select[title="Category possible values"] > option').appendTo('#names');
var catvalues =$('select[title="Category possible values"]')[0];

$('select[title="ProductName"]').change(function() {

    var val = $(this).children("option:selected").text();  
    $('select[title="Category possible values"]').empty();
    var opts=names.clone();
    opts.children().each(function(idx, el) {
        if (el.text.indexOf(val) >= 0)
        {
            catvalues.add(el);
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: What is `catvalues` in FFX/IE?

Comment: Finally got it working by changing the line from  
<code>
catvalues.add(el);
</code>
to 

    catvalues.appendChild(el);

its really difficult some time to understand the compatibility issues, however its working now, please comment if there is something better then this.